# How do I put a <sup> tag inside a <sup> tag?

Tags: html, mindmapping

I need to write the expression *e to the -x square* using HTML inside Freeplane. Can you please tell me how to do it? 
When I try to use one tag after another like this: 
**f(x)=e<sup>-x<sup>2</sup></sup>** 
and hit OK, the program automatically transforms my code in 
**f(x)=e<sup>-x2</sup>**.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a **span** tag inside **sup** tag and **CSS**.

```css
sup span {
vertical-align: super;
font-size: .8em;
}
```

```html
<p>f(x)=e<sup>-x<span>2</span></sup></p>
```

Comment: Why not put the `sup` inside the `sup` and change your style selector to `sup sup { }`?

Comment: Freeplane automatically deletes the css code and reverts me back to f(x)=e-x2. Could you please reply with the whole piece of code? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Even if you put the CSS inline?
<p>f(x)=e<sup>-x<span style="vertical-align: super; font-size: .8em;">2</span></sup></p>

Comment: Still doesn't work. At least now I am sure it's a bug from them, so I will let them know. Thank you for your help.